# How to calculate the AND operation of an IPaddress and a subnet mask in C?

Tags: c, ip-address, subnet

I have an IPaddress and subnet mask, both in unsigned long; how can I AND both of these and check whether my incoming ipaddress (ip2) belongs to the same subnet or not?

like:

```
if (ip1 & subnet == ip2 & subnet)
    then same subnet.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parentheses - the precedence levels are confusing:

```
if ((ip1 & subnet) == (ip2 & subnet))
    ...
```

The original code was effectively the same as:

```
if (ip1 & (subnet == ip2) & subnet)
    ...
```

Comment: A good compiler should warn about this. GCC does, if invoked with `-Wall`.

Answer (score 1):

Just like you did it:

```
if ((ip1 & subnet) == (ip2 & subnet))
  printf("same subnet 0%x", subnet);
```

(just added the () to insure the computation is done in the right order).